# Subversion and LDAP User Groups

Tags: apache, svn, active-directory, ldap

I'm new to Apache, Subversion and Jira and am ultimately trying to get Subversion working with LDAP Groups (to control who can access the Repository) along with 'Path-based Authorization' to fine tune which areas authenticated users can access.

I have configured Subversion LDAP settings found under 'Administration\Authentication' and now all AD users have full control over the repository. I'd like to restrict this to users within the AD user group: SVN_Users

I have really struggled to find documentation (hence writing this post) and mostly what I have, has been cobbled together from people trying to acheive similar things on StackOverflow.

My understanding (maybe incorrectly) is that LDAP Group access control requires the module:mod_authnz_ldap to be loaded and configured in C:\Subversion\data\conf\httpd.conf

## My httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "C:\Subversion"
ServerName subversion.COMPANYNAME.LOCAL
LoadModule dav_module C:/Subversion/lib/modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module C:/Subversion/lib/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module C:/Subversion/lib/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module C:/Subversion/lib/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
Include "data/conf/csvn_modules_httpd.conf"
Include "data/conf/csvn_main_httpd.conf"
Include "data/conf/csvn_logging.conf"
Include "data/conf/csvn_default_dirs_httpd.conf"
Include "data/conf/svn_viewvc_httpd.conf"
Include "data/conf/csvn_misc_httpd.conf"

<Location /svn/COMPANYNAME/>
AuthType basic
AuthName COMPANYNAME
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://VM-DC-01:389/dc=COMPANYNAME,dc=LOCAL?sAMAccountName" NONE
AuthLDAPBindDN "DN=LDAP Auth,OU=USERS,OU=NETWORK,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=LOCAL"
AuthLDAPBindPassword <LDAP Auth Password>
Require ldap-group "CN=SVN_Users,OU=USRGROUPS,OU=NETWORK,DC=COMPANYNAME,DC=LOCAL"
```

However, all users are still able to login, rather than just those in the AD group.

What am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm struggling to see what it is.

Also, can anyone explain what the 'LDAP Filter' is under 'Administration\Authentication'? I had a similar field when setting up Jira which was used to only allow access to people in the 'Jira*' AD group. The filter I used for this was '(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=jira-*))' Applying this to the 'Administration\Authentication' section prevents everybody from accessing SVN.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#examples sample 4 as base?

Comment: Also http://www.linuxweblog.com/apache-ldap-authentication